# displaying last login using timestamp on php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the last-login date and time of the user when the user logs in. I have a timestamp in my database. I'm able to store the time of login every time the user logs in but being new to PHP, I'm unable to display the same.Please help me to display timestamp type variables stored in the database using MySQL and PHP.

I'm posting my code for index.php where I want to display the last login time and date.

code for session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and 
password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("exp", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from user where 
username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

code for index.php:

```
 <?php
 include('session.php');
 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<h1>Hello

<i><?php echo $login_session; 

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastlog) FROM user WHERE 
 username=  '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login_user']). "' ");

 if($result)
                {
                    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    echo $data['lastlog'];
                }

                mysql_query("UPDATE user SET lastlog = now() WHERE
  username=  '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login_user']). "'");

                ?></i>

                </h1>


 </body>
</html>`
```

THE COLUMN FOR TIME STAMP IN MY DATABASE IS THE LAST LOG. Also, help me with storing and displaying the date of creation. please help me with this problem...
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: I quit reading after I saw `mysql_`. Use prepared statements, I suggest PDO.

Comment: why you used still mysql it's deprecated try mysqli

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: The indentation here is absolutely chaotic. I hope your actual code is more organized than this otherwise it'll be impossible to maintain.